# silex passing form data to another page?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm really new to silex and symfony. This is my first foray into silex. I've got code that created my form in my app.php file from a little hacking and copying and pasting from documentation.

Now how do i pass this data to another page?

I would like to create a page that just dumps the post/get array to give me an idea how to pass around get/post variables.

Here's part of my app file:

```
<?php
/** /src/app.php */
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

    /**
     * Register new application
     */
    $app = new Application();
    // skip to the form part ...
        $app->match('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
            // some default data for when the form is displayed the first time
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'Your name',
                'email' => 'Your email',
            );

            $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', $data)
                ->add('name')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('gender', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(1 => 'male', 2 => 'female'),
                    'expanded' => true,
                ))
                ->getForm();

            if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
                $form->bindRequest($request);

                if ($form->isValid()) {
                    $data = $form->getData();

                    // do something with the data

                    // redirect somewhere
                    return $app->redirect('completed');
                }
            }

            // display the form
            return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array('form' => $form->createView()));
        });
```

Would i then create a page like so?

```
<?php  // app.php  
    $app->match('complete') use function ($app) {
          // sorry psuedocode
         foreach ($REQUEST as $key=> $var) {
         echo "$key: $var";
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a forward. http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#fowards

```
// where params is the values from your POST
$subRequest = Request::create('/otherpage', 'GET', $params);

return $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Could you anticipate any reason there'd be a seg-fault error? I get one when I pass the $params through.

Comment: How does one supposed to access the sent parameters? How would it be with a POST request? Please explain. The provided answer is not enough